# Which Responsive Web Design Framework is validated with w3c validator?

Tags: frameworks, responsive-design, w3c-validation

I'm googling with any keywords about the responsive web design framework that is validated with w3c validator HTML5+CSS3, but all frameworks that I found are not validated.

Is there responsive web design framework like that?

**UPDATE** : These are what i found :

- http://www.gumbyframework.com/
- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- ...

Comment: can you display the one that you find in your question?

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) definition:

> ...is made up of member organizations which maintain full-time staff for the purpose of working together in the development of standards for the World Wide Web...

It doesn't validate frameworks, frameworks are made on top of this standarts.

Good responsive design framework I could recommend: [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: but bootstrap is very badly in CSS! 800+ errors found from w3c validator

Comment: not all new features of css3 (and the -webkit, -moz, -0 and -ms-filters extensions and such) are yet approved by the w3c. But are needed for diferent browser and their engines. In the future it will be a standart for many of this features... but not right now I'm afraid. Take that in consideration

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by your term 'framework'.  This can mean different things to different people.

As for me, I develop sites with Joomla using the Gantry Framework and have fairly good success although not all of my client websites validate 100% due to some 3rd party addons.

However, the focus should not be on getting a 100% validation result, although that is nice when it happens, but to create a website that is functional AND works!  I do validation on every website (although not every page).  I use it to find and correct 'potential' problems.

Validation is more of a guide to assist in correcting 'potential' problems as some validation errors might cause a web page to not display properly in all browsers.  However, I have found that many validation errors will not impede the ability of a web page to display just fine in different browsers.